# How can I toggle a table column using mustache?

Tags: mustache

Suppose I have an order listing. The order is made up of order-items and
items may have a specified material or not. The order is rendered as a
table and the column for material should only be shown if (at least) one
of the items has it. In other words, an empty "material" column should
not be shown.

Here is an example template:

(pardon my HTML. I didn't go looking that up.)

```
<table>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>quantity</th>
  <th>made of</th>
  {{#items}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{qty}}</td>
      <td>{{material}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/items}}
</table>
```

Suppose Wile E. Coyote is trying to catch Road Runner and orders some TNT and
rope:

```
{
  "customer" : "Wile E. Coyote",
  "items" :
  [
    { "name" : "TNT", "qty" : 2 },
    { "name" : "rope", "qty" : 10, "material" : "nylon" }
  ]
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
<table>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>quantity</th>
  <th>made of</th>
  <tr>
    <td>TNT</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>rope</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>nylon</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But if he orders an anvil instead of a rope:

```
{
  "customer" : "Wile E. Coyote",
  "items" :
  [
    { "name" : "TNT", "qty" : 2 },
    { "name" : "anvil", "qty" : 1 }
  ]
}
```

an ugly empty "made of" column will be rendered:

```
<table>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>quantity</th>
  <th>material</th>
  <tr>
    <td>TNT</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>anvil</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I modify my template to get this instead?

```
<table>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>quantity</th>
  <tr>
    <td>TNT</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>anvil</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I also control the JSON and can modify that too. But I would prefer
not to.

Comment: Mustache is logicless - it will render as you have defined. I think your best bet is to manipulate the rendered DOM with javascript (or jQuery?) to hide the column is no values are present.

Comment: We already have a solution like that in place, but would like to eliminate client-side code for that. I think we're going with changing the JSON unless some solution shows up here.

Comment: Another alternative is to have two templates and render either one depending on your object literal - not a fan of this option (nor the first one I suggested!)...